# UISegmentedControl becomes distorted after flip animation

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I am using `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight` on the main window while switching the main view controller of a `UINavigationController` by setting `viewControllers` array.

Everything works fine, except the `UISegmentedControl` in the navigation bar becomes distorted about 1 out of 5 times randomly. If anyone has seen something similar and found a solution, please let me know.

The resulting screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried seeing if there is any distortion at all (could be bad drawing code), with `NSStringFromCGAffineTransform`?

Comment: I just checked and it is identity. Also, when user interaction happens (even with other UI elements on screen), the distortion goes away.

Comment: Does it happens also on the device ?

Comment: Yes. As soon as another view appears, or tableview is scrolled, the distortion goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Why go such a primitive route when iOS defines much higher level transition API's.  For example, `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` uses much the same animation as `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`, but is ***much*** simpler to use in general.  It also allows for the presentation of navigation controllers (as I can see in the screenshot), which in turn allows views to be pushed from inside said modal view.

Comment: Hmm, correct me if I am wrong, but isn't `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` only used when presenting a modal view controller? I just tried with my code, but I don't think it works in other presentation methods. In my case, I am just switching out view controllers in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: That in itself is a bit dangerous, and is probably why you're getting the distortion.  If you want to be safe, set the segmented control's transform property to CGAffineTransformIdentity and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UISegmentedControl` AFTER the animation completes?